# Ruby on Rails: Can't render the edit view of a nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm new to rails and I'm stuck with a problem I can't seem to understand. I'll explain my scenario:

I have a User model which was created using Devise. I've created another model called Skill (math:integer science:integer) which references user:

```
- skill belongs_to :user 
- user has_one :skill
```

I've modified the routes file so that skill has nested routes within user:

```
# Users (Devise)
devise_for :users, :path_names => { :sign_up => "register"}

# Skills
resources :users do
  resource :skills
end
```

I've created a SkillsController with the actions edit, and update. The code is the following:

```
class SkillsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @skill = get_skill(@user)
  end

  def update
    @skill = Skill.find(params[:id])

    if (@skill.update_attributes(params[:skill]))
      redirect_to(root_url, {:notice => 'Your skills were successfully updated.'})
    else
      render :action => "edit"
    end
  end

  # the user might have been created without skills, so it will be nil on the first usage
  # ToDo: extend Devise UserController to create an empty skill on the create action
  def get_skill(user)
    if !(user.skill)
      user.skill = Skill.new
      user.save
    end
    user.skill
  end
end
```

Finnally, my views/skills/edit.html.erb view looks like the following:

```
<%= form_for(@skill) do |skill_form| %>

    <div>
      <%= skill_form.label :math %><br />
      <%= skill_form.text_field :math %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= skill_form.submit 'Save' %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

Whenever I try to go to the skills edit form (http://localhost:3000/users/1/skills/edit), the following error is thrown:

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Skills#edit 

No route matches {:controller=>"skills"}

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for(@skill) do |skill_form| %>
2: 
3:     <div>
```

I know I must be doing something wrong... just can't figure out what :|

Thanks in advance,
Bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `get_skill` method should be creating a skill like this instead:

```
def get_skill
  user.skill || user.create_skill
end
```

The `form_for` for this because you've got skills nested inside of users in the routes should be this:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @skill] do |f| %>
```

Comment: Should it not be `user.skill || user.build_skill.save!; user.skill` ?

Comment: I've tryed as Ryan and Zabba suggest and now the following error happens:NoMethodError in Skills#edit

undefined method `skill_path' for #<#<Class:0x386faa8>:0x386bcf8>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for(@skill) do |skill_form| %>

Comment: @Zabba: Actually `create_skill` will do that. Now if you'd be so kind as to remove your downvote.

Comment: @Bruno: I've updated my answer with the correct form_for line now.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your help. using the form_for and changing the get_skill the way you suggest fixes the issue only if in my routes.rb I set the nested skill to plurar resources.
However, I don't like the routes generated this way (users/1/skills/1/edit) because each user will ONLY have one skill, so there is no need to set the skill_id on the path, that is why I was using the singular resource on the nested skill. If I keep this singular resource on the routes.rb the following error occurs: undefined method `user_skill_path' for #<#<Class:0x380fd48>:0x3756660> on the form_for line. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I managed to fix the problem for the singular resources. I was setting resource: skills. It must be resource: skill. This way everything works fine! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Change the form_for from:

```
form_for(@skill)
```

to:

```
form_for([@skill.user, @skill])
```